# strcmp(x, str) is wrong?

Tags: c++

As a beginner of C++, I feel so puzzled on this point for a long time, the program is to tell the appearing times of each word in a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    vector<string> str;
vector<int> t;
while (cin >> x)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j != str.size(); j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(x,str[j]) == 0)
            t[j]++;
        k = 1;
    }
    if (k == 0)
    { 
        str.push_back(x);  
        t.push_back(1);     
    }  

}

for (int i = 0; i != str.size(); i++ )
{
    cout << str[i] << "   " << t[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
C++\code\3.3.cpp(17) : error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I find no result on the Internet after a long-time searching. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `y`?.....also `std::string` cannot be used with `std::strcmp`.

Comment: If you need the behaviour of strcmp, you can use string::compare for strings.

Answer (score 1):

If x and y are C++ strings then you just say `x == y`. You are trying to use a C function `strcmp` on a C++ object.

If y is a C style string then the same code `x == y` will also work because the C style string will automatically be converted to a C++ style string, however in this case it might be better to do `strcmp(x.c_str(), y) == 0` because this avoids the automatic conversion.

Only if x and y are both C style strings should you do `strcmp(x, y) == 0`.

Comment: There is no automatic conversion to be afraid of (except maybe in the description of the function's effect, it works *as-if* doing `x == string(y)`). There is a `string::compare(const char *)` overload that will take care of everything.

Comment: maybe i haven't get out of the style of c programming.. thanks too much !  :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because strcmp expect a `const char*` that is different from a `std::string`. You can retrieve a const char * invoking method `c_str()` on that string:

```
if (strcmp(x.c_str(),y) == 0)
```

In addition to that, it seems that 'y' parameter is declared nowhere inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

X is a string, and strcmp compares const char*
To convert a string to a const char* use

```
x.c_str ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler expect a `const char*` or something convertable to `const char*`. But `std::string` is not implicitly convertable to `const char*`.

If you want to use `strcmp`, you have to use the method `c_str` to get a `const char*`. But in your case, it's probably better to use `==` which is overloaded to work with std::string.

Answer (score -1):

jahhaj is right, but if you want to call a C function on a string, you can use `string_instance.c_str()` to get the string as a `const char *`